# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string' when destructing an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm destructing an object as following:

```
const { lang, ...params } = ctx.query;
```

But TS gives me an error in this line:

```
if (!value.includes(params[key])) return false;
```

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I get similar error with destructure of `event.queryStringParameters` using `lambda` functions, but I get the error with the destructure `{var1,var2}=event.queryStringParameters` on var1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.includes(params[key] as string)` (or `.includes(<string>params[key])`) to tell Typescript you know it's a string.

Answer (score 2):

first check if params[key] is defined

```
if (params && params[key]) {...
```

Comment: Hi Niek. You can use `` to wrap the code you write.
`like this piece`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is understanding your property represented by `params[key]` has either a type of an `array`, or a `string`, the property is even `undefined` because maybe `key` does not exist in your object.

You could first check if the property exists
Then you could check if the type of your property is a `string` this way

```js
if (params[key] && typeof params[key] === string && !value.includes(params[key])) return false;
```

Ideally you would have a parent `if` block like this

```js
if(params[key] && typeof params[key] === string){
   //The property exists and if of type string, do your thing with it.
   if (!value.includes(params[key])) return false;
}else{
   //Why it's not the type you expected?
   //Do something, log or throw an error for example
}
```

This way Typescript knows it will only reach the child `if` when the `params[key]` property is really a string, and then the typescript checker/compiler will not complain about that uncertainty.